# What does operator >>= mean

Tags: javascript

What exactly does the `>>=` operator mean in JavaScript? I mean, I use it often in Haskell to work with monadic values, but I saw this weird (and **syntactically valid!**) operator in a JavaScript code:

```
function repeatArray$(arr, n){
  for (var r = []; n > 0; (n >>= 1) && (arr = arr.concat(arr)))
    if (n & 1) r.push.apply(r, arr);
  return r;
}
```

I know what the function does, but I can't resolve the utility here or what it can do. Is it a composition of two operators, such as `-->` (`--` `>`) with bitwise operations? I didn't find a specification about that.

Comment: It means `n = n >> 1`. Which shift all digits in `n` to right by 1. See [Shorthand operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Assignment_operators)

Comment: It's the same as any other operator with assignment at the end. `+=` `-=` `/=` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x >>= y` is [Right Shift assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Right_shift_assignment). Equivalent to `x = x >> y`.

[MDN Assignment Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)