# What n&1 and n>>=1 mean?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was doing this exercise : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-binary-numbers/problem and I found this code, but I didn't understand what the condition with n&1 and n>>=1 do here.

```
 //C++ program to convert a decimal
// number to binary number

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,count=0,max=0;
    cin >> n;

    while(n)
    {
        if (n&1)
            count++;
        else
            count = 0;
        if (max < count)
            max = count;
        n>>=1;
    }
    cout << max;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [What is (x & 1) and (x >>= 1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922606/what-is-x-1-and-x-1)

Comment: Sorry to be that guy, but duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922606/what-is-x-1-and-x-1

EDIT: @t.niese got it a second before me :)

Comment: They are operators.

Comment: You shouldn't use hackerrank or similar sites to learn a programing language.  Instead, you should consider to use a good [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn the basics of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (n&1)
```

checks whether `n` is odd by doing a bitwise and.

```
n>>=1;
```

shifts the bits of `n` to the right by one bit.

Comment: Detail: `if (n&1)` incorrectly tests for odd-ness on those long forgotten [1s' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) machines when `n < 0`.  Not a real concern in 2020.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` is a bitwise-AND operator and evaluates the expression in either true or false (when the expression is conditional), it's pretty much similar to `x % 2`, i.e. this condition:

```
if (n & 1) {
    //...
}

// is equal to

if (n % 2) {
    // ...
}
```

OTOH, `n >>= 1` shifts right `n` by a bit.

Comment: "it's similar to x % 2 which obviously returns either 1 or 0 as remainder"  --> `x%2` returns 0, 1 or -1.

Comment: `The & is a bitwise-AND operator and evaluates either true or false` this is highly misleading, a bitwise operator does not evaluate to true or false. If you have `01111 & 01001` it will evaluate to `01001`. If the result of the `&` is used in an `if` then this result itself will be evaluated to a boolean.

Comment: @t.niese updated, Thanks.